# How to use embed Angular UiGrid in AngularJs Component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I try to embed a ui-grid in a component, and the embedded ui-grid doesnt render

I built a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UOZbTaOelXjgedMr) to visualize the problem.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <scripts> ... </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl">
      DataGrid in HTML
      <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: $ctrl.myData }" class="grid"></div>
      <h1>Template/ Component</h1>
      <hero-detail hero="$ctrl.hero" myData="$ctrl.myData"}"</hero-detail>
    </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
  .component('heroDetail', {
  template: `
      <div>
        DataGrid in Template
        <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: $ctrl.myData }" class="grid"></div>
        <span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>
        
      </div>
  `,
  bindings: {
    hero: '=',
    myData: '='
  }
});

function MainCtrl() {
  this.hero = {name: 'Spawn'};
  this.myData = [
    {
        firstName: "Cox",
        lastName: "Carney",
        company: "Enormo",
        employed: true
    },
    ...
  ];
}
```

Do you have an idea how to arrive at a workable solution?

**Thanks for your input!**

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24871#issuecomment-404850356), all camelCase bindings in the component are translated to kabab-case in the html. So your component reference in the `index.html` needs to be changed from

```
<hero-detail hero="$ctrl.hero" myData="$ctrl.myData"></hero-detail>
```

into

```
<hero-detail hero="$ctrl.hero" my-data="$ctrl.myData"></hero-detail>
```

Also, a side note, you have a typo where `="$ctrl.myData"}"</hero-detail>` needs to be changed to `="$ctrl.myData"></hero-detail>`